# Integrating Tweakpane for Debugging in a Vue Three.js Boilerplate Project

Tags: vue.js, three.js

I'm currently working with the THRE-BOILER-TEMPLATE, a Vue.js and Three.js boilerplate, and I'm looking to add a debugging UI using Tweakpane. Given the unique structure of this boilerplate, which is described as "the best one," I'm curious about the most logical approach to integrate Tweakpane for real-time debugging.

So far, I've initiated the setup within a DebugManager.js file like this:

```
import { Pane } from "tweakpane";

class DebugManager {
  PARAMS = {
    panelColor: { r: 255, g: 255, b: 255 },
    // Additional parameters can be added here
  };

  constructor() {
    this.pane = new Pane({ title: "Debug" }); // Initialize the pane with a title

    // Add a color control for debugging panel color
    this.pane.addInput(this.PARAMS, "panelColor", {
      label: "Panel Color",
      format: "rgb",
    });
  }
}

export default new DebugManager();
```

```
import Device from "@/pure/Device";
import Common from "@/graphics/Common";
import Input from "@/graphics/Input";
import DebugManager from "@/graphics/debugManager";

import { EffectComposer } from "three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js";
import { RenderPass } from "three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/RenderPass.js";
import { ShaderPass } from "three/examples/jsm/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js";
import { Uniform } from "three";

import vertexShader from "./shaders/vertex.glsl";
import fragmentShader from "./shaders/transition.glsl";

import { Vector2, Vector3 } from "three";
import gsap from "gsap";

export default class PostProcessing {
  constructor() {
    const { width, height } = Device.viewport;
    this.passes = {};
    this.composers = {};

    this.composer = new EffectComposer(Common.renderer);
    this.composer.addPass(new RenderPass(Common.scene, Common.camera));

    this.mainPass = new ShaderPass({
      uniforms: {
        res: new Uniform(new Vector2(width * Device.pixelRatio, height * Device.pixelRatio)),
        time: new Uniform(0),
        slowMotion: new Uniform(0),
        coords: new Uniform(new Vector2(Input.coords.x, Input.coords.y)),
        panelColor: new Uniform(new Vector3(0)),
      },
      vertexShader,
      fragmentShader,
    });
    this.composer.addPass(this.mainPass);
  }

  render(t) {
    this.mainPass.uniforms.time.value = t;
    this.mainPass.uniforms.slowMotion.value = t / 2;

    // Update coordinates smoothly using GSAP
    gsap.to(this.mainPass.uniforms.coords.value, {
      x: Input.coords.x,
      y: Input.coords.y,
      duration: 0.3,
      ease: "linear",
    });

    // Update panel color based on DebugManager settings
    this.mainPass.uniforms.panelColor.value.set(
      DebugManager.PARAMS.panelColor.r / 255,
      DebugManager.PARAMS.panelColor.g / 255,
      DebugManager.PARAMS.panelColor.b / 255
    );

    this.composer.render();
  }

  dispose() {
    this.composer.reset();
  }

  resize() {
    const { width, height } = Device.viewport;
    this.composer.setSize(width, height);
    this.mainPass.material.uniforms.res.value.set(width * Device.pixelRatio, height * Device.pixelRatio);
  }
}
```

My questions are:

Is this the recommended way to integrate Tweakpane for debugging purposes in a project structured like the THRE-BOILER-TEMPLATE?
Are there more efficient or cleaner methods to achieve real-time debugging with Tweakpane in Vue.js and Three.js projects?
I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to better approach this integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a Debug implementation sample on [`simluation-test`](https://github.com/trinketmage/vue-three-boilerplate/tree/simluation-test) branch.

- Your `DebugManager` class should be initiate inside `Common.js` (cause it is a common object [ref](https://github.com/trinketmage/vue-three-boilerplate/blob/simluation-test/src/graphics/Common.js#L39)).
- Inside your graphic's pipeline main file, you need to instantiate that debug on conditional (in this case we use the fact that we add `#debug` to the url [ref](https://github.com/trinketmage/vue-three-boilerplate/blob/simluation-test/src/graphics/index.js#L16-L19)).
- Inside your output you need to traverse components to check if some have debug's implementation ([ref](https://github.com/trinketmage/vue-three-boilerplate/blob/simluation-test/src/graphics/Ouput.js#L75-L81)).
- Each components can have it's own debug methods ([ref](https://github.com/trinketmage/vue-three-boilerplate/blob/simluation-test/src/graphics/components/Powers.js#L41-L68)).